# How many ways to instantiate objects in c++？What‘s the difference between them

Tags: c++, initialization

I am a newcomer when its come to c++, when I study something about virtual functions and pure virtual functions, I found it's different than when I instantiate an object in different ways. This puzzles me a lot. I'll appreciate if you could help. The following are the codes and output.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class A {
public:
    int va;
    int vb;

    virtual void m1() {
        cout << "this is A's m1() method" << endl;
    }

    void m3() {
        cout << "this is A's m3() method" << endl;
    }
};

class B : public A {
public:
    void m1() {
        cout << "this is B's m1() method" << endl;
    }

    void m2() {
        cout << "this is B's m2() method" << endl;
    }

    void m3() {
        cout << "this is B's m3() method" << endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    cout << "start" << endl;
    A a1 = B();
    a1.m1();
    a1.m3();
    cout << "===================" << endl;
    A *a2;
    a2 = new B();
    a2->m1();
    a2->m3();
    delete[]a2;
    /*
        output：
        this is A's m1() method
        this is A's m3() method
        ===================
        this is B's m1() method
        this is A's m3() method
    */
    return 0;
}
```

I'd like to know what's the difference between `A a1 = B();` and `A *a2; a2 = new B();`. Thank you for doing the help.

Comment: Hint: When do `a1` and `a2` get destroyed? Also, you aren't instantiating anything. You only instantiate templates :)

Comment: Read a [good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list/388282#388282)

Comment: Compiler Explorer => http://godbolt.com/ There you can look into how *pointer type* works, how *vtable machanism* works in action. And also how objects get constructed on stack and on the heap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you happen to know/learn Java? Things work a bit different in C++.

`A a1` is an object of type `A`, regardless of how you construct it. In particular:

```
A a1 = B();
```

Does the following:

- creates a temporary object of type `B`
- creates an object `a1` of type `A` using a built-in copy constructor. It will *copy* the contents of the temporary to `a1`. Only the part `A` of the temporary will be copied though.
- the temporary `B` object is destroyed.

That is why all methods on `a1` are real `A` methods. No virtual mechanism will reach B's methods, because `a1` is not a `B`-type object.

---

`A* a2` on the other hand is a pointer to any object of type `A` or derivative. It is merely a *pointer*, on itself it does not represent an object.

Now, when you assign `new B()` to it, it will point to an object of actual type `B`. Calling virtual methods through this pointer will reach `B`'s methonds as you probably expected.

btw. a single object referenced through a pointer should deleted through `delete a2`. You use `delete [] a2` if you have an array.

Comment: Very clearly. Thank you for the wonderful answer, this suddenly made me understand !

Answer (score 0):

*I'd like to know what's the difference between `A a1 = B();` and `A *a2; a2 = new B();`.*

`A a1 = B();` will slice the B temporary to the A stack variable.  Any additional member variables or behaviors of B will be discarded.  The A stack variable `a1` will be destructed at the end of the scope.

`A *a2; a2 = new B();` will have a A pointer which points to a global store allocated B object.  The `a2` variable will point to that B object, which continues to be a B object.  The virtual methods of A that are overridden in B will use the B methods.  The non-virtual methods of A will be accessible through the A pointer, but the additional methods of B (virtual or non-virtual) will not be accessible, unless casting is used.

The `delete[]a2;` is undefined behavior, and on my machine will crash the application.  Because the B object was allocated on the global store using `new B()`, it should be deleted using `delete a2;`.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question, I've do some research after watching your answer, it is wrong for me to use delete[] here absolutely, but it's strange that my machine didn't crash on the application, by the way, my compiler is MinGW.